# Stage is bigger than the screen in LibGDX, how to fit it in the screen?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm developing a game in libGDX, and the levels in my grid contains a grid actor which contains mirrors inside [(see my game)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfIZ4.jpg). The problem is that the grid is too big and I want to be able to see all the stage.

I'm using an OrthographicCamera and an ExtendViewport.

I tried using frustrum (I don't really know what it is): I create four BoundingBox (left, right, top and down) which are placed out of the grid. I set the camera position to the middle of the grid actor and i make a loop zooming the camera until the boxes are in the frustrum, but I don't know if it is the best solution...

Comment: Will all your levels be the same size, or will the zoom need to be different depending on what stage you're on?

Comment: I don't know exactly what behaviour you're hoping for, but `ExtendViewport` should work all on its own. Just use something like `new Stage(new ExtendViewport(viewWidth, viewHeight))` where width and height are equal to the dimensions of your grid. When you resize the window, the content will be scaled to fit the viewport.

Comment: fyi: frustum: the portion of a cone or pyramid which remains after its upper part has been cut off by a plane parallel to its base, or which is intercepted between two such planes. So basically you have your view with a near and far clipping.
Also, a "stage" has no dimensions, so it cannot be outside the screen. however, the actors on the stage can be.

Comment: No, levels will be different size (Players will be able to create their own levels), but I can get the size of the grid. I just want to calculate the zoom that I need to be able to see all the grid.

Comment: @DavidS Thank you a lot, it works!! I set the minimum world's size equals to the grid size plus some space in show() (because the grid is null in the constructor). Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a [FitViewport](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/FitViewport.html), which will make sure you don't 'spill' off the screen.

FYI, the frustum is used to determine depth of your camera- how far it can see. I agree that that won't help you in this situation.

Comment: There are six planes in the frustum. The near and far planes affect how far the camera can see. The other four planes define the boundaries of what you can see at the edges of the screen. So the way the OP is using them makes sense, although it's weird to do a loop instead of directly calculating what's needed, and it's needlessly complicated when the camera is orthographic.